# Accessing OMR Scanner through web application

Tags: html, web, sdk, scanning, activex-exe

I want to access OMR Scanner through web application. I have search for it in google and found ScanTool SDK, but I am looking for similar functionality but open source. My basic requirement is below:

- There will a web interface for the user.
- User can select OMR scanner from the web page drop-down.
- User can do the scanning of the document

**NOTE:** I have seen similar functionality for TWAIN scanner. But I want it for OMR scanner. As TWAIN scanner generate image data but OMR scanner generate image as well as raw data of response present in OMR sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer her regarding scanning via the web:
[How can I scan a document using ASP.net MVC 5 with the help of Twain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761786/how-can-i-scan-a-document-using-asp-net-mvc-5-with-the-help-of-twain/39133035?noredirect=1#comment65620222_39133035)

Basically you will need to install some sort of client side service that will interface with your scanner's driver in order to scan via the web as there is built in security functionality that prevents the browser from interfacing directly with the client's scanner.